# Php does not echo text. looks like a constant? is this broken?

Tags: php

this is the most strange thing that has ever happened to me with php

This is the code source code:

```
echo 'rsi_color_by_number '.$i+$di.' = rsicoloredbackground >'.$i+$di .' and rsicoloredbackground <'. $i+$di+1 ."? black:#ffffff00 \n";
```

and it echoes only this:

```
1? black:#ffffff00
```

Comment: why + ? shoudn't be .  $i+$di  --->   $i.$di   are these numbers? try to echo only the variables are you sure they are not null?

Comment: please provide more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence. `+` and `.` have the same precedence, and left associativity, so

```
'string' . $i + $di . 'string2'
```

is treated as

```
(('string' . $i) + $di) . 'string2'
```

This will try to use `'string' . $i` as a number and add that to `$di`.

You can solve this with explicit parentheses:

```
echo 'rsi_color_by_number '.($i+$di).' = rsicoloredbackground >'.($i+$di) .' and rsicoloredbackground <'. ($i+$di+1) ."? black:#ffffff00 \n";
```

But when you find yourself repeating `$i + $di` in the code, it can be useful to assign it to a variable:

```
$newi = $i + $di;
echo 'rsi_color_by_number '.$newi.' = rsicoloredbackground >'.$newi.' and rsicoloredbackground <'. ($newi+1) ."? black:#ffffff00 \n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I am so rusty it makes total sense and it is working now. I was so scared that my beloved php had broke on me but no, I can see clearly now. =)

Answer (score 1):

If $i and $di are strings, try this:

```
echo 'rsi_color_by_number '.$i.$di.' = rsicoloredbackground >'.$i.$di .' and rsicoloredbackground <'. $i.($di+1) ."? black:#ffffff00 \n";
```

If $i and $di are numbers, try this:

```
$num = (int)$i + (int)$di;


echo "rsi_color_by_number {$num} = rsicoloredbackground > {$num} and rsicoloredbackground < ". (int)$num + 1 . "? black:#ffffff00 \n";
```

If that works for you, you should do calculations before your echo statement, to keep your code clean and precise and prevent against repeating the same calculation more often and making mistakes... the (int) before any variable will cast that variable as an integer; whereas before it is uncasted... Check php.net for type casting.

Without seeng what $i and $di is, it's difficult to know what you are doing.

If you don't know the values of those variables, don't forget to use var_dump

```
var_dump($i);
var_dump($di);
```

Comment: Your code has the same precedence problem when you use `. (int)$num + 1 .`. Also, there's no need to use `(int)` there, since `$num` is an integer.

Comment: In fact, you don't need `(int)` anywhere, `+` will convert its arguments to numbers.

Comment: "numbers"; but not integers, which he is using for color codes, apparently; so yes, you do need (int); as they could be adding as floats (default).

Comment: Can you see the rest of his code? Me either. That's how.

Comment: Give him the benefit of the doubt, fractions don't generally happen by accident. No code that's generating color codes like this would use floats.

Comment: Benefit of the doubt? So be ignorant to possibility? What are you even saying? ... His code isn't generating color codes,  he is, manually... by assembling variables into an echoed string.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "fractions" in computing... Fractions are for humans, decimals are for machines... And you're right... They don't happen by accident, they happen by default.

Comment: You know what I mean -- numbers that have values after the decimal point. They don't happen by accident, you have to do things like division to get them. That doesn't happen in code that's working with things like array indexes, for-loops with integer increments, etc. Do you really put `(int)` in all your code, just in case a number magically turns into a non-integer?

Comment: I've been programming for 40 years and never felt the need to do something like that.

Comment: No, I code properly, initializing my variables when the scope begins. But neither you, nor I can see the rest of his code, but looking at it from here... I doubt this is the crux of the coding issues. Why you're defending what you can't see is very interesting to me. If you've been coding for 40 years and the quality of your code is worth a grain of salt, you wouldn't be arguing right now.